Introduce "secp256k1" tag?
Currently, there is no tag for "secp256k1".
Given how important Bitcoin has become, it might be time to have such a tag.
Doing so would make it easier for users to find and answer secp256k1-related questions.

I've changed the tags from feature request to discussion / voting, as anybody with enough rep can introduce such a tag, so no mod or team operation is required.

No, we should not introduce a secp256k1 tag. Just tagging something with elliptic-curve and / or dsa is enough.

No, we should not introduce a secp256k1 tag. Just a single curve specification is too specific to merit a tag of its own. Instead we could introduce a koblitz tag, as the curve is associated with a Koblitz curve.

What about having [tag:secp256k1] which is an alias to [tag:koblitz]?

Interesting idea. Maybe I'm taking this too literally, but I don't like the idea because secp256k1 is obviously not an alias of it, it's a specialization of it... Do you want me to introduce another answer for it or shall we check if this one gets voted up and decide then? As I don't think they can win separately I'd suggest the latter.

Yes, we should introduce a secp256k1 tag. This specific curve has become important enough to merit its own tag.
b degnan: Besides that, people may not know that secp256 would be related to ECC and DSA.

A large number of users will know secp256k1, but they might not know it is associated with a Koblitz curve.  "Secp256k1" is one of the curve options in GPG, and some users may know it from there and want to follow its questions and answers on this site.

Then what about secp192k1? It exists. Will there be a tag explosion for every "popular" named curve?

secp256k1 is much more noteworthy than secp192k1.  I can name several major applications of secp256k1 off the top of my head; I can't name any for secp192k1.
